# How to recover deleted profile in Chrome 14, especially bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome

I accidentally hit this button...

[image]

And it seems to have deleted all my bookmarks and everything, instantly, without confirmation.

How can I get them back?

Comment: Do you have sync enabled?

Comment: @Sathya: No. [15char]